# Can someone please explain why these flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

The following flags were recently declined. Can someone please explain me where my reasoning was wrong for the flags to be declined?

1. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5820740/2246380) is about LaTeX and the answer which I exactly can't recall was a couple of words about a other product which looked like promoting a product and I flagged it as *spam* which was declined but the answer got deleted.

[image]

2. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676517/2246380) looks like an answer as it has code related to the question hence ruled out *not an answer* flag. It is low quality as it has just 3 lines of code but no explanation about where to use the code or any other form of explanation hence I used the *very low quality* flag as it has content problems which are not salvageable through editing as mentioned in the flag description.

[image]

3. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28662009/2246380) looks like a comment than an answer and I raised the *not an answer* flag which got declined

[image]

4. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28653863/2246380) is asking for code review and is suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as agreed by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653863/advice-on-good-programming-practice-code-supplied#comment45604687_28653863). I couldn't find an option for flagging for migration to code review. I raised the *other* flag and mentioned it.

[image]

Comment: No, you don't need to ask multiple questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few but here are my thoughts.

The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682758/426671) you flagged as spam. There is no spam in this answer. Spam flags should be for promotional type of posts like "Hey, buy this Gucci bag", etc. Spam flags carry significant penalties to users so we are hesitant to accept these flags, especially when they don't fit.

The [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676517/426671) you flagged as VLQ, there was also a Not An Answer flag on this at the same time. Both were declined - one it is an answer, two this is not VLQ.  It's not gibberish and it doesn't need to be deleted immediately.

The [third one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28662009/426671) appears to be an answer about how the user resolved the same problem. Since it appears to be an answer, even though not the best one, the flag was declined.

The [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653863/advice-on-good-programming-practice-code-supplied) to migrate to Code Review.  In its current state, it doesn't fit for Code Review.  We only like to migrate quality questions and this didn't meet the standard we would want.

Comment: So What was the right flag for the first one which got it deleted?

Comment: @Sri IMO, you shouldn't have flagged the first one.  If you felt it wasn't a quality answer, then downvote, comment, and move on.

Answer (score 5):

1. Suggesting a product be used as a solution to a question isn't necessarily spam.  It may be a low quality answer if it contains nothing more than a product name, as is the case here, but it's not spam.  Spam would be advertising content unrelated to the question, posting the content to lots of different places, posting content that one is affiliated with, etc.
2. An answer being poorly explained is not a reason to delete it.  It's a reason to downvote it.
3. It's providing an answer to the question.  It's stating a course of action that the author feels will fix the problem.  You may think that it's wrong, poorly explained, etc. and as a result you could downvote it, but it's clearly an *attempt* to answer the question, whether or not it succeeded.
4. Questions are only migrated when they would be very high quality questions on the target site.  Dumping a ton of code and asking, "is there anything I could do better" is not an appropriate CR question.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's been deleted now, but the mods may have not wanted to feed the answer to the internal spam mechanisms. They tend to be very careful about accepting spam flags. I can't view the question to confirm this, so be prepared for a mod to say otherwise.
2. Is a grey area that we see often in the low quality posts queue, it's usually better to do what someone else did and leave a comment on the answer asking for more information. It can be salvageable through editing (by the person who wrote the answer) if this is done, so it's not *quite* low quality enough for the flag. I would downvote it though, until editing is done.
3. Is an answer to the question explaining how they fixed the issue that they were getting. While it may have been brute force, and a comment could have said the same, it is still an answer.
4. Only a limited subset of questions are migrated, and only if they are considered to be of a high enough quality. That one wasn't, but leaving a comment *recommending CodeReview.SE* is fine though, as long as they read the on-topic guidelines first.